# Is there any iPhone app that will sync .txt files locally or be able to decrypt files stored in dropbox

Tags: iphone, applications, data-synchronization

I need a way to sync plain text files from a mac that are usually edited with Notational Velocity and they must not pass through any cloud based storage unless they are stored encrypted with a key I create.

I've looked at Evernote, Simplenote, and multiple dropbox based apps but I have yet to find a good solution.

The closest I've found has been MobileOrg with Emacs org-mode to encrypt the files and sync them through dropbox or my own webdav server but being a Vim user this is not optimal. And since I'm looking into this to help someone who isn't as proficient with computers I can't tell him to start up Emacs just to sync plain text between his Mac and iPhone.

(I really don't see the point in having everything passing through the "cloud" other than to provide more information for targeted advertising.)

So is anyone aware of any iPhone app that will edit plain text files and sync them through the local network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to use [simpletext.ws](http://simpletext.ws), since the source is available I can use my own server to sync notes in my local network without having to worry about encryption. And on the iPhone I use the [WriteRoom](http://www.hogbaysoftware.com/products/writeroom) app to search and edit notes.

(As this is my first time using any stackexchange site I'm not sure if I should include this in the original question or answer it myself... apologies in case I'm not following the proper way of using the site.)

Comment: this is perfect. you could also have answered in the same way you'd answer any question, without saying "my solution was". it's all fine! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think that [Codebook](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/codebook-secure-notebook/id361921889?mt=8) provides what you need!

- 256 AES Encryption
- ...
- Backup & MultiDevice sync via Dropbox (in-App purchase)

Comment: Codebook does seem like a very good app although without a proper way to get those notes into plain text from the sqlite db it's doesn't solve much.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use [ikeepass](http://ikeepass.de/) or [mykeepass](http://mykeepass.blogspot.com/) for that, even if the original purpose of [keepass](http://keepass.info/) is storing passwords, since version 2.x it has an internal viewer for text among others.

Comment: iKeepass is not available in other countries other than Canada and USA, 1Password is, and I do know it has a notes feature but not very practical, it also caused me to lose some note I was editing when a phone call came up.

Comment: @melvin 1password is the midterm between keepass and lastpass. I prefer the later, but you dont want everything in the cloud. and i agree. to me, the lack of offline backups is the worst aspect of lastpass. I'm surprised with ikeepass restriction, tho. I'll add the other option and hope it doesn't have same restrictions.